# In systemverilog is there a way to condition on a type?

Tags: system-verilog, parameterized-types

So I am using a parameterized type in a common module.

Is there a way to say:
 if( type == TYPE1 ) assign the struct one way
 else if( type == TYPE2 ) assign another way

I was picturing this in a generate block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the type operator do a generate-if/case, or procedural if/case like:

```
real r;

if ( type(r) == type(real) ) ...
```

But unfortunately the code in all branches still must successfully compile, regardless of the condition. You will not be able to reference struct member that does not exist.

```
  typedef struct {int a;} s1_t;
  typedef struct {int a;int b;} s2_t;
  s1_t s;
 initial
      #1 // procedural-if
    if (type(s) == type(s1_t))
      $display("%m s.a = %0d",s.a);
    else if (type(s) == type(s2_t))
      $display("%m s.b ==%0d",s.b); // this will not compile
```

Answer (score 2):

There is `type()` operator described in [IEEE1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 6.23. Example usage from from the LRM:

> ```
> bit[12:0] A_bus, B_bus;
> parameter typebus_t = type(A_bus);
> generate
>   case(type(bus_t))
>     type(bit[12:0]): addfixed_int #(bus_t) (A_bus,B_bus);
>     type(real): add_float #(type(A_bus)) (A_bus,B_bus);
>   endcase
> endgenerate
> ```

There is also `$typename()` described in [IEEE1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 20.6.1. `$typename()` return s string of the type. Example usage from from the LRM:

> ```
> // source code            // $typename would return
> typedef bitnode;          // "bit"
> node [2:0] X;             // "bit [2:0]"
> int signedY;              // "int"
> packageA;
> enum{A,B,C=99} X;         // "enum{A=32'sd0,B=32'sd1,C=32'sd99}A::e$1"
> typedef bit[9:1'b1] word; // "A::bit[9:1]" 
> endpackage: A
> importA::*;
> moduletop;
> typedef struct{node A,B;} AB_t;
> AB_t AB[10];              // "struct{bit A;bit B;}top.AB_t$[0:9]"
> ...
> endmodule
> ```